# Using Apache's ssl certificates when it is accessed via Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have been running an Apache webserver on my machine for a long while, serving various sites via https. I had to install a Nginx server on the same box, and set it up to reverse proxy most requests to the Apache webserver via port 8080. I can access the sites hosted on the Apache server, but the SSL certificate in use is still the one associated with the Nginx server, not the one referred to in the Apache .conf files. How can I direct Nginx to defer to Apache's pre-configured SSL when it forwards a request?

Answer (score 0):

In those case a reverse proxy/frontend is configured, the frontend has to have the certificates.

For the vhosts that NGinx will be frontend, the certificates have to be exported for NGinx, and on the Apache site those vhosts will be (re)configured as HTTP answering for the IP NGinx comes from (in this case localhost).

So NGinx will be the SSL frontend. Also has an added bonus, in very busy sites, NGinx and Apache can be installed in different servers, and the NGinx server will do SSL offloading.